# Какой-то непонятный текст из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка

Надо, чтобы программа выводила текст из файла, в который я что-то написал.

Вот код:

```py
FILENAME = "text.txt"
f = open(FILENAME, 'r')
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

В моем файле text.txt написано: `Привет! У меня кое-что не работает(`.

Когда я запускаю код, мне в консоль пишет непонятные символы:

> РџСЂРёРІРµС‚! РЈ РјРµРЅСЏ РєРѕРµ-С‡С‚Рѕ РЅРµ СЂР°Р±РѕС‚Р°РµС‚(

Если что, пользуюсь PyCharm Community. Текстовой файл создан там же, где и файл .py.

Comment: Кодировку файла нужно указать при открытии.

Comment: @Victor Пожалуйста, комментируйте  предлагаемые правки, не надо там писать безсмысленные фразы. Их тоже читают, чтобы быстрее понять содержание правки.

Comment: Приму к сведению :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно знать кодировку файла. Можно например в обычном блокноте посмотреть, когда нажимаете "сохранить как" там внизу будет. Или попробуйте сразу так:

```
FILENAME = "text.txt"
f = open(FILENAME, mode='r', encoding='UTF-8')
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]